# Question on modal verbs

Tags: modal-verbs

Can we form the negative form of this sentence, she used to swim on Sunday’, in the following ways?
1) She doesn’t use to swim on Sunday.
2) She didn’t use to swim on Sunday.

In thw first sentence why do we use infinitive form of ‘use’ with doesn’t, even if ‘used to’ is semi modal?

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise.  We wouldn't use either of your sentences as the negation—although your second is close. It should be ***used*** *to*. Also, it should really be *Sundays* (plural)—in both the positive and negative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid negative:

> She [did not use to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did%20not%20use%20to%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdid%20not%20use%20to%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20like%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20give%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20read%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdid%20not%20use%20to%20exercise%3B%2Cc0) swim on Sundays, but now she has taken up the practice.

You could also say

> She [never used to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never%20used%20to%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cnever%20used%20to%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20come%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20express%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20denote%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20signify%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever%20used%20to%20any%3B%2Cc0) swim on Sundays, but now she has taken up the practice.

Your version with **does** is not a valid tense for referring to the past.